# Grails, Custom Validatable object for updating

Tags: validation, grails, groovy

I have a custom validation for my Users. It works fine but for creation but I face an error when I want to update a user. There are some fields that are not available in update section such as username, password and email and these fields shouldn't be null.

```
import grails.validation.Validateable

class UserCommand implements Validateable {
    Long id
    String firstName
    String lastName
    String username
    String password
    String email
    UserStatus status = UserStatus.CREATED


    static constraints = {
        firstName nullable: false, blank: false
        lastName nullable: false, blank: false
        username nullable: false, blank: false, validator: { val, obj ->
            if (obj.id) {
                if (User.countByUsernameAndIdNotEqual(val,obj.id)) {
                    return "user.already.exist"
                }
            } else {
                if (User.countByUsername(val)) {
                    return "user.already.exist"
                }
            }
        }
        password nullable: false, blank: false
        email nullable: false, blank: false, validator: { val, obj ->
            if (obj.id) {
                if (User.countByEmailAndIdNotEqual(val,obj.id)) {
                    return "user.already.exist"
                }
            } else {
                if (User.countByEmail(val)) {
                    return "user.already.exist"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

In my controller, when I want to validate the inputs, it gives me a `NullPointerException` because mentioned fields shouldn't be null.

```
    def update(UserCommand command) {
        if(command.validate()) {
            try {
                user = userService.update(command)
            } catch (ValidationException e) {
                respond user.errors, view: 'edit'
                return
            }
        }
    }
```

and this is `edit.gsp`:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Edit information</title>
    <meta name="layout" content="main"/>
    <asset:stylesheet src="bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
</head>
<body>
<g:form resource="${this.user}" controller="user" action="update" method="put">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <div class="inputWithIcon">
                    <input type="text" class="custom-input" name="firstName" placeholder="First Name" value="${this.user.firstName}">
                    <i class="fa fa-id-badge fa-lg fa-fw" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <div class="inputWithIcon">
                    <input type="text" class="custom-input" name="lastName" placeholder="Last Name" value="${this.user.lastName}">
                    <i class="fa fa-id-card fa-lg fa-fw" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-4">
                <div class="inputWithIcon">
                    <input type="text" class="custom-input" name="country" placeholder="Country" value="${this.user.country}">
                    <i class="fa fa-globe fa-lg fa-fw" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-8">
                <div class="inputWithIcon">
                    <textarea  type="text" class="custom-input" name="address" placeholder="Address" rows="3">${this.user.address}</textarea>
                    <i class="fa fa-address-card fa-lg fa-fw" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <button type="submit" class="custom-button edit">Update</button>
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>
</g:form>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

What is the best way to deal with Validations (maybe I don't get the concept entirely)? and how to fix this issue?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You should create an UpdateUser command - or even a base command that CreateUser and UpdateUser can extend from instead of trying to include multiple concepts into one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think what you may want to do is load the `UserCommand` in the `update` method, the update the fields based on parameters that come in.

So instead of your update method, something like

```
def update() {
    UserCommand command = UserCommand.get(params.id)
    command.firstName = params.firstName // and more based on whatever you can update

    if(command.validate()) {
        try {
            user = userService.update(command)
        } catch (ValidationException e) {
            respond user.errors, view: 'edit'
            return
        }
    }
}
```

You could also have all of the non-updateable fields on your edit.gsp in `<input type='hidden'/>` but my preference is to not send data like that across, as someone with malicious intent could still update those fields fairly easily by using DOM inspector or similar.

Answer (score 0):

You may be doing this the hard way as well.

These can be built into your User GORM Class thus saving you from having to build out a separate CommandObject.

Though I'm pretty sure you knew that. Am just putting this in here for others who may be searching this topic.